# Ns3 adding a new module-- gcc not finding included headers

Tags: c++, linux, include-path, ns-3

I am trying to add a new custom module to NS3[Network Simulator 3](http://www.nsnam.org) and I am having trouble making the header files of the module visible to the compiler.

Here is what I did:

1.I followed this[guide](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/new-modules.html) to add a new noc module using the createModule script.

2.I went on and copied my module files into the new created noc directory and made waf(the build system ns3 uses) aware of my new files through editing the wscript file.

3.It is my understanding that with all this set up(I probably wrong) that with this set up,running the waf commands to rebuild ns3 should rebuild ns3 with my new module.

To build I give the following commands:

```
  ./waf clean

  ./waf configure --enable examples

  ./waf build
```

The system goes on and builds ns3 and when it gets to my noc module it throws errors about objects of a Scalar Class not being defined in the scope.This usually means that I haven't included the header files but I have tried to copy them with other module files and included them with statements like #include "nstime.h" .With this the problem persisted. I tried copying the header with the definition of my class in the /usr/include directory and inlcuded it with #include  and the problem is still there.

I realize this is a long post ,I am sorry but I would really appreciate it if somebody helped point out what I am missing.Thank you for your time.

Comment: `#include "nstime.h>` is not valid - it needs to be either `#include <nstime.h>` or `#include "nstime.h"`

Comment: Sorry it way a typo.I did use #include "nstime.h" and the problem is still there.Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The only difference between `#include "nstime.h"` and `#include <nstime.h>` is that the former looks in current directory _in addition_ (and in preference) to the directories listed on command line and the standard directories.

Comment: You shouldn't have write permissions to `/usr/include` when compiling. If you do, you are doing something horribly wrong. Never compile, or do any other non-maintenance work, under root.

Comment: @user2368528: OK- as a general rule you should never re-type code when asking a question - always copy and paste from the original, so that you don't introduce typos etc.

Comment: I first compiled and the compiler threw errors about missing my header files.I desperatery copied them in usr/include because I read the compiler looks there for include files but even when I copy them there it is still not finding them.What can I do to make it find the included files?

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are you trying to compile? NS3 itself, or some code that uses it?

Comment: I will copy 'n paste in the code from now on :-)

Comment: Do you have NS3 itself compiled? Did you _install_ it as well? If you are compiling something that depends on it, it may expect NS3 itself to be installed rather than just compiled.

Comment: NS3 does not have a Network on Chip module by default .So I am trying to compile this [link](https://code.google.com/p/unimap/) module but I am having those problems.

Comment: I have installed ns3 successfully .I am just trying to make the custom module visible to it.

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong if you don't show the exact steps you are doing. Edit the question, it will be a lot of typing.

Comment: Thank you Jan Hudec for your help.I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: I would suggest you show the exact error reported by gcc, as well as the exact code that is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure in your wscript file that you add the dependencies of your module to other ns-3 modules as explained [here](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/new-modules.html#step-2-create-your-new-module-based-on-the-template-module).